# Every Ansible command responds with "abort"

Tags: ansible

When I run any Ansible command the response is always `abort`. For example:

```sh
ansible --version   

# Or:
ansible-playbook -i production site.yml --diff --check
```

Response:

```
[1]    78576 abort      ansible --version
```

Any idea why or how to fix? I updated Ansible but error remained the same. Things used to work in the past but it's been a few months since I've used Ansible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem here. It's a problem with OpenSSL:
https://nbari.com/post/python-quit-unexpectedly-macos/

The steps to fix:

```
brew reinstall openssl

cd /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib libssl.dylib
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.dylib libcrypto.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something specific on your system which has been misconfigured.

- re-trace your steps which could’ve led to this error
- Try to reinstall Python / Ansible
- use ‘ps aux | grep ansible’ to see if there are other Ansible processes running
- virtualenv?
- worst case ; reinstall system

Comment: Thanks, will try that. I see there's an Ansible process running whose pid keeps changing. Maybe a restart will help. I recently moved machines and also changed my shell from bash to zsh. Wonder if that had an impact.

Comment: Your issue is most likely that Ansible task which is running and keeps changing PID.

Comment: Finally found the answer. Thanks for the help